# help with JOIN in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How in MySQL, I want to get the results from the post table. I do this perfectly. However I would like to get the individual Likes from the like table and the comments from the Comments table.

How could I do this using the JOIN function? Each of the tables have the postID in common (id for the table Posts).

Comment: You can find all the needed info on joins [here](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=mysql+join+tutorial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `posts`
INNER JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`postId` = `posts`.`postId`
INNER JOIN `likes` ON `likes`.`postId` = `posts`.`postId`
WHERE `posts`.`postId` = ?
```

Comment: This is not true. The joins in this query are constrained by the conditions in the ON statements within the joins.

Comment: yes, but if you have a post with 5 comments and 10 likes, you will get 50 rows for that post.

Comment: True, but this is what was requested by the question. My answer answers the original question, but Michael Robinson's answer is a better overall solution.

Comment: @KOGI I believe it is cartesian, isn't it? Every resulting row will contain the post, some of the lines will contain a comment, and some a like.

Comment: True, this does answer the question as asked.

Comment: @joakimdahlstrom I honestly don't know, you may be right about the name of it. I originally interpreted skajfes's comment as claiming that I would have the result of joining all 3 tables with no conditions. Wherein if each of the 3 tables had 100 rows, then the result would be 1,000,000 rows.

Comment: @KOBI I'm not completely sure about the name, but I think it can also be referred to as a 'cross join'. It works when only using two tables like 'topics' and 'articles', but I guess the third table will ruin most of the fun.. am I right?

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a join, get the posts, then for each post, get the likes & comments separately.

Psuedocode:

- Get all the posts

  - Declare an array to store them in
  - Iterate the fetched posts, and for each of them:

    - Get the 'likes' and 'comments' separately from the posts (i.e. in their own queries). Get them as an array. Add them to the posts array like `$posts['likes'] = $likes`.
    - Convert the constructed array to json and echo it out: `echo json_encode($posts)`

Comment: I am then outputting the results as JSON though.

Comment: If you're using JSON, create a wrapper object that contains the post information, likes and comments as separate properties of the wrapper object.

Comment: @Ryan Doherty, I wouldn't know how to do that, could you provide an example? @Michael Robinson, how could I do that?

Comment: My answer answers your question, but this is a better overall solution.

Comment: I will be accepting your answer @KOGI, but I will be using this method. Thanks @Michael Robinson.

Comment: @RhumSHISH glad we could help :)

Comment: Also, one idea if you want to avoid multiple db queries, loop through the first list of posts, build up an array of Post ID's with the data you already have, then perform one query to get all the likes for the list of post ID's then farm the results off to their appropriate post id back in the original array. do the same for comments.

Comment: Just a question about this. Is this the 'right way' to approach a situation like this, or does it go against the concept of the relational databases?

Comment: @Scuzzy, @Michael Robinson, my code for doing makes the web page not load :S $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY date DESC") or die(mysql_error()); 
  $array = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $array[] = $row;
   $postID = $row['id'];
   while ($ra = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE postID = '$postID'"))) {
    $array['comments'] = $ra;
   }
   while ($rd = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Likes WHERE postID = '$postID'"))) {
    $array['likes'] = $rd;
   }
  }
  echo json_encode($array);

Comment: There is no way I can read all that code inside a comment. If this issue is sufficiently different to the current one, please consider opening a new question about it?